# .net 5 project requiring .net core 3.1 to be installed

Tags: c#, .net, monogame

I am attempting to upgrade a MonoGame project I am working on to .net 5. I have upgraded all of my nuget packages. Then I changed the target framework to .net 5. The project compiles fine and runs perfectly. However, when I try to run it through my github actions workflow with only installing the .net 5 tools, the compilation fails with the following message:

> ```
> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
> framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
>   - The following frameworks were found:
>       5.0.0 at [/home/runner/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]    You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework
> and/or SDK.
> ```

If I try to install .net core 3.1 tools also, it will compile.

The project I'm using is [here](https://github.com/hmumm/chip8emulator), [this](https://github.com/hmumm/chip8emulator/pull/41) is the particular pull request that is failing. (If you are reading this later the commit I am referring to is [a876e47](https://github.com/hmumm/chip8emulator/pull/41/commits/a876e47137449ea44dde6ab3025613d1980451a2))

I have also tried a pre-release version of Serilog.Sinks.Console thinking that was the issue. That did not work. I don't understand what is requiring the Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 since under Dependencies I can only see version 5.0.0 being required.

Comment: probably, it's caused by internal monogames' tools, they require 3.1: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/7400#issuecomment-725422676

Comment: Yeah that seems to be it. I guess I didn't understand what the tools meant exactly, But when I look in Dependencies -> Packages it has MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task which is definitely a tool. I'll have to wait for them to upgrade that, Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

As [Exploding Kitten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743754/exploding-kitten) pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64948186/net-5-project-requiring-net-core-3-1-to-be-installed/68241621#comment114825525_64948186)

> probably, it's caused by internal monogames' tools, they require 3.1: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/7400#issuecomment-725422676

which explains the need for .NET Core 3.1.